# Get Firefox settings from outdated Windows to new Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I had Win XP, with Firefox latest. I didn't know what is Firefox profile folder there. Now this XP is replaced with Win 7 (new installation, not update). How can I "import" settings of Firefox from "old XP" to new Win7?

I cannot boot to old XP, it's deleted in boot ini file. But I can access all files of XP on disk.

Comment: are u able to access my documents and os installation file drives of xp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [This Tutorial](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_finding-your-profile-without-opening-firefox) on how to find your profile data - you should be able to copy it straight from the old location to the new one.

the source folder will be

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<Windows  XPlogin/user name>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\(profile folder)
```

And then you paste any found profiles into

```
C:\Users\<Windows 7 login/user name>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\(profile folder)
```

Comment: Good, tks. It's `%appdata%` folder.